# How can add a close button in CPTLayerHostingView using Coreplot

Tags: ios, ipad, core-plot

How can add a close button in `CPTLayerHostingView` using Coreplot in an iPad application.

I created a graph in a `CPTLayerHostingView` using CorePlot. But now I'd like to add a Close or Done button to the `CPTLayerHostingView`.
Give me a suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`CPTLayerHostingView` applies a flip transform to its children, so if you add a button or any other view inside it, the subview will appear upside down. Instead, add the hosting view and your button to the same parent view.

Comment: It looks like you have the right idea in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223583/ios-coreplot-implemet-share-button-to-scatter-plot).